# How to control external scripts to where they can inject content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an external script which I have included onto my website through a `<script>` tag. This external script injects a set of html into where that `<script>` tag is placed.

For instance, if I had that script that in `#div1`, the injected set of code will be appended directly into `#div1`.

```
<div id="div1">
  <script src="http://url/to/script.js></script>
  //injected html will appear in the dom here
</div>
<div id="preferredTarget">
</div>
```

However, I may prefer having my script tag in the `head` of the page.

```
<head>
 <script src="http://url/to/script.js></script>
</head>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="preferredTarget">
  //i want my injected html to appear here
</div>
```

Also, sometimes, if my target div was created at runtime, the external script cannot find that target div at the time it was loaded because the target div may not be ready yet.

Are there any methods in controlling the placeholder where an external script would inject its content into?

Comment: It pretty much depends on the external script.

Comment: @CBroe So there is nothing I can do with it other than to slap that script tag all over the page at weird places like in a `li` or `div`, etc?

Comment: It's out of your control. The external script is meant to be used in a different way then you try to use it. You can either use it as it's meant or you don't use it at all; that are pretty much your options. Or you could try to hack its behaviour, but unless you've done this before, you have no idea how many problems you might get and need to fix; most of the time it's not worth it. Can you tell us, wich script we're talking about?

Comment: Well you could for example write your own script that dynamically creates and inserts script elements referring that external script … Your own script could be embedded in the head only, and then use classes/ids/whatever to identify the elements in the document that the external script should be inserted into/after. But if it is supposed to get more elaborate than that, then you’ll most likely need the help of the other party that provides the script, and have them adapt it accordingly.